# Powershell issue for ucs

Tags: powershell

Below is my script for UCS

```
Remove-Item F:\Logs\UCS\*
$server= Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter UCS IP'
$Chasis= '(ChassisId 1)'
connect-UCS $server
Get-UcsTechSupport -PathPattern 'F:\Logs\UCS\${ucs}-techsupp-chassis.tar' -RemoveFromUcs -TimeoutSec 1200 -$Chasis -CimcId all
```

I am getting below error when I try to run it..

```
Get-UcsTechSupport : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-ChassisId 1'.
At F:\Logs\ucs1.ps1:5 char:1
+ Get-UcsTechSupport -PathPattern 'F:\Logs\UCS\${ucs}-techsupp-chassis.tar' -Remov ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-UcsTechSupport], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Cisco.Ucs.Cmdlets.GetUcsTechSupport
```

Comment: Please format your code. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
-$Chasis
```

Which resolves to:

```
-(ChassisId 1)
```

Pay particular attention to the hyphen (`-`)

PS is seeing this as the *name* of a parameter.

I don't know the arguments for the CmdLet you're using, so this corrected code is just an example:

```
... -TimeoutSec 1200 -ParameterName $Chasis -CimcId all
```

Comment: Its not confusing a parameter name it is having an issue with positional assignment. Since there is no parameter named for that value in the cmdlet call PowerShell will try to match it positionally. `Get-UcsTechSupport` does not support that hence the error.

Comment: Get-UcsTechSupport -PathPattern 'F:\Logs\UCS\${ucs}-techsupp-chassis.tar' -RemoveFromUcs -TimeoutSec 1200 -ChassisId 1 -CimcId all       - This works fine for me. But I want to call Chassis number in variable so that it can accept input and when i am trying this then it returns error